# How can I remove "All Site Content" from the Blog Navigator in SharePoint 2010?

Tags: blog

How can I remove "All Site Content" from the Blog Navigator in SharePoint 2010? I removed it from v4master and "All Site Content" disappears on all of the site pages (which is what I wanted) but it did not go away on the blog pages. Does anyone know how I can remove it from the blog pages??? Any suggestions will be GREATLY appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Dave Wise suggested, you can use CSS (e.g. by adding it to the masterpage with SharePoint Designer) like this:

```
<style type="text/css">
#s4-leftpanel-content .ms-quicklaunchouter .ms-quickLaunch .s4-specialNavLinkList li+li
{
    display: none;
}
</style>
```

But you should keep in mind that a technical savvy user can view the page source, or turn off your CSS, to discover and use the link.

If you want a foolproof way with a SharePoint 2010 Blog you need to remove it from your masterpage **AND** also modify the default.aspx homepage, category.aspx of the Categories list, date.aspx and monthlyarchive.aspx of the Posts list, because it is hardwired into those.

To do this with SharePoint Designer 2010 open the page in question and locate the following codeblock in sourcecode view:

```
<SharePoint:ClusteredSPLinkButton
    id="idNavLinkViewAllV4"
    runat="server"
    PermissionsString="ViewFormPages"
    NavigateUrl="~site/_layouts/viewlsts.aspx"
    ImageClass="s4-specialNavIcon"
    ImageUrl="/_layouts/images/fgimg.png"
    ImageWidth=16
    ImageHeight=16
    OffsetX=0
    OffsetY=0
    Text="<%$Resources:wss,quiklnch_allcontent_short%>"
    accesskey="<%$Resources:wss,quiklnch_allcontent_AK%>"/>
```

Once found, add a `Visible=false` right after `<SharePoint:ClusteredSPLinkButton`

Note that I would go with the CSS trick because modifying all those aspx pages could have adverse side effects which I haven't tested all by myself.

If you want a real 100 percent foolproof way you could develop a custom ASP.NET/SharePoint WebControl with C# code to remove it without touching any masterpage or pulling CSS tricks. Such a WebControl could also include custom code to prevent users from directly entering the link. But that requires quite some development knowledge.

Comment: I used the CSS option and it worked like a charm. Thank you Sig Weber!!!!

Answer (score 1):

It can be done via CSS. You merely need to track down the right selector in your environment.  Find the container that holds that content and set it to `display:none`

If you have access to the master page then you can also set it to be [security trimmed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webcontrols.spsecuritytrimmedcontrol.aspx) and set the [permission level](http://raiumair.wordpress.com/2009/08/05/security-trim-control/) to some admin level permission like 'ManageWeb'.  You can even set the control itself to `visible="false"`

Comment: What if I deleted it?????? Can I still get to your suggested approaches in the master page?